# Select a number randomly and then select a higher number randomly python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a psychological experiment for my PhD thesis. I am pretty new to python. What I am looking for is that I need to select a *number* from a list of numbers and then again select a *number* which should in *one case* higher than the previous one and *in another case* lower than the previous one.

The main list of pool of numbers is:

```
digit = range(0,30)
if cong = 'yes':
## select a number for a variable d1 from digit and
## select another number for a variable d2 from digit which is higher than  
## d1
else:
## select a number for a variable d1 from digit and
## select another number for variable d2 which is lower than d1
```

I have tried solving this but I guess not that expert right now. 
Would be grateful if anyone could help me solve this.

PS: This is my first question so I am now much aware about the standard practice of forum participation.

Thanks
Vatsal

Answer (score 2):

```
LO, HI = 0, 30
d1 = random.randint(LO + 1, HI - 1) # Select a number between 0 and 30, exclusive
if cong == 'yes':
    d2 = random.randint(d1 + 1, HI) # Select a bigger number
else:    
    d2 = random.randint(LO, d1 - 1) # Select a smaller number
```

Comment: @TomKarzes to be fair, so does the experiment. You can't select a higher number than the highest number in your range.

Comment: @TomKarzes You are right. I restricted the original range to [1,29].

Comment: I copied the incorrect single equal sign from the original post. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, looks like the exceptions should be gone now.  No idea what OP actually wants though...

Answer (score 2):

`randint()` and `randrange()` should do the job:

```
import random

num_range = a, b  #Specify the initial range here. (0, 30) for you.
num_0 = random.randrange(a+1, b)  #Boundaries aren't included.
if cong == "yes":
    num_1 = random.randint(num_0+1, b)  #Select a larger number.
else:
    num_1 = random.randint(a, num_0-1)  #Select a smaller number.
```

Comment: @TomKarzes What about my answer?

Comment: Also not sure what purpose assigning to `num_range` serves, since it's not used anywhere.